# Java programming double dimensional arrays

Tags: java, arrays

My aim here is to type a simple code to take in number input from the user and print a simple matrix. The code I typed seems to compile but doesn't work during run time! My code is something like this:

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    class Arr

   {
    public static void main()
    {Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

    int a[ ][ ]=new int[2][3];




    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<2;y++)
        {
            a[i][y]=in.nextInt();
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
        for(int y=0;y<2;y++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[i][y]);
        }
    }

}
}
```

At the same time could you suggest a solution if I were to transpose the matrix inputted by the user?

Comment: `My code is something like this` Is this your code or isn't it? In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: START BY NOT SHOUTING

Comment: Shouting??.. Yes this is my code it complies! When i run the code! I do not get any output, Im using BlueJ!

Comment: SHOUTING is when you use all capitals in your text.  Or in your case, in the title of your question.  It is interpreted as rudeness / attention seeking behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the `main` method incorrectly. The proper `main` method signature is

```
public static void main (String[] args)
```

That's why the compiler is not compiling your code.

Comment: I tried replacing the code! It still doesn't seem to show any output when i run the program! It compiles perfectly

Comment: @AbhishekJ Are you able to enter things into the CONSOLE?

Comment: @AbhishekJ The code you posted **will not** compile. Either your IDE is helping you in ways it shouldn't, or the code you posted is not the code you are compiling successfully.

Comment: No Im using BlueJ and it does not open the terminal window and allow me to input numbers.!

Comment: I don't know what BlueJ is, but compile and execute your class from the command line.

Comment: I tried! Still doesn't work! All I want is a basic 2D array program which takes numbers from a user and prints it in the form of a matrix. Example:   The user inputs the numbers 123456 it shud be printed as a 2*3 matrix

Comment: Your program works when I compile it here. What happens when you compile it from the command line? (When I say it works, I mean it gives some output. It doesn't do exactly what you want yet.